# Azure Node.js Table Entity Update

Tags: node.js, azure, geolocation

I'm trying to update a table entity during data insertion using server Node script. Here is what I'm trying to do. I have a Address table which has a column named geolocation of type "geography". When a user updates the Address, I'm using npm-geocoder to get the latitude and longitude to update the geolocation column.

Here is the code snippet.

```
var table = module.exports = require('azure-mobile-apps').table();

table.dynamicSchema = true;

table.insert(function (context) {

    var address = context.item.lines1 + ' ' + context.item.lines2 + ' ' + context.item.city + ' ' + context.item.state + ' ' + context.item.zip;
    var geocoderProvider = 'google';
    var httpAdapter = 'https';
    var extra = {
        apiKey: '',
        formatter: null
    };

    var geocoder = require('node-geocoder')(geocoderProvider, httpAdapter, extra);
    geocoder.geocode(address)
    .then(function(res) {
        var geolocation = "POINT("+ res[0].longitude + "  " + res[0].latitude +")";
        console.log("Value of Geolocation is ", geolocation);
        context.item.geolocation = geolocation;
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log("Error ", err);
    });

    return context.execute();
});
```

However, i don't see the table being updated with the geolocation. Any pointers?

I looked at few samples available online but they are mostly based on previous mobile services where the insert method signature is different for ex:-

```
function insert(item, user, request) { 
    var queryString = "INSERT INTO Place (title, description, location) VALUES (?, ?, geography::STPointFromText('POINT(' + ? + ' '
+ ? + ')', 4326))";         
    mssql.query(queryString, [item.title, item.description, item.longitude.toString(), item.latitude.toString()], { 
                success: function() { 
                     request.respond(statusCodes.OK, {}); 
                } 
          });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`context.execute()` is being called before the `geocode()` promise is resolved. Move `context.execute()` inside the callback and return the promise from the function...

```
table.insert(function (context) {

    // ...

    var geocoder = require('node-geocoder')(geocoderProvider, httpAdapter, extra);

    return geocoder.geocode(address)
        .then(function(res) {
            var geolocation = "POINT("+ res[0].longitude + "  " + res[0].latitude +")";
            console.log("Value of Geolocation is ", geolocation);
            context.item.geolocation = geolocation;
            return context.execute();
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log("Error ", err);
        });

});
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that and it adds the geolocation into the database perfectly. But on the response i get 

{
  "error": "The item does not exist"
} 

I guess insert block returns this message without waiting for the geocode block to be executed. Is there any way to get the results after geolocation is added?

Comment: Where's the response that you're talking about? Is it in the code snippet you posted?

Comment: Yes.. When I moved  the context.execute method inside the callback I got 'this item does not exist' as result although it added an entry in the db with geolocation

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, I think you can try to use the `update` operation instead of the `insert` operation for the table to update an existed object. And if the table had the column named `geolocation`, the `dynamicSchema` property enabled seems to be not necessary for the table.

Meanwhile, you can try to check the table access property for the `update` operation, please see the setions `How to: Require Authentication for access to tables` & `How to: Disable access to specific table operations` of the doc https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-node-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/.